# Hosting more than 1 website through 1 public IP

Tags: networking, website

I have 2 websites e.g: http://abc.xyz.co.in and http://123.xyz.co.in:8089 hosted in a single physical server(Windows Server 2012) in port 80 and 8089. The server is in MZ zone and it is behind External DNS, load balancer,firewall etc.
My xyz.co.in domain is resolved into a public IP say: 11.22.33.44.

Now, I dont my users to remember the port numbers for every websites that I host on this server. How can I simplify the URL by removing the port number from it.

Comment: Use [Host Headers in IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/302992/3363219)

Comment: You want name-based virtual hosting.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which web server you're using.  If you're using IIS then [The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like's comment](http://superuser.com/questions/1078617/hosting-more-than-1-website-through-1-public-ip#comment-1524217) does help point you in a good direction.  Namely, [Use host Headers in IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/302992/3363219).

If the users aren't going to be required to specify a different port number, then TCP port 80 will be used.  The web server will need some method of determining which website to provide.  Options can include different directories (e.g. http://example.com/site1 and http://example.com/site2), or different host names (e.g., http://example.com and http://example.net).  You can use name resolution, such as DNS, to have different host names.  The "host" field in the HTTP header is how you can get the web server to respond differently to those different names.

To configure this, the section of Apache's configuration is called VirtualHost.  With IIS, use the "Use host headers" option.  For other web servers, the precise method may be different.